# Proof that derivative is tangent to curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How would I prove that the direction of the derivative of a parametrized curve $\vec r'(t) = \left({r_1}'(t), {r_2}'(t), \dots, {r_k}'(t)\right)$ for $t \in [a,b]$ is tangent to the curve $\vec r(t)$?

I'm not even sure how to define tangent here.  Is there some geometric definition I can use to convince myself that the derivative is always in that direction?

Comment: I define tangent space of $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ at a point $a$ as the set $T_aS$ of vectors $v$ as it exists $\gamma:]-\varepsilon,+\varepsilon[\to S$ as $\gamma(0)=a$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$, thus you haven't anything to show (with here $S=r(I)$ if $I$ is the interval where $r$ is defined).